# Different sums that preserve divisibility

Tags: number-theory

From my Math GRE book.

> If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers satisfying $13 | 4x - 5y + 2z$, which one of the following sums must also be divisible by $13$?
>
> (A) x + 13y - z (B) 6x - 10y - z (C) x - y - 2z (D) -7x + 12y + 3z (E) -5x + 3y - 4z

Is there a procedure, given integers $x$, $y$, $z$ and a linear combination $P(x, y, z)$ to write out all of the linear combinations that satisfy $n | P(x, y, z)$?

Comment: +1 for asking this question. It's very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x,y,z$ are integers such that $13{\,\mid\,}(4x - 5y + 2z)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&13{\,\mid\,}(4x - 5y + 2z)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&4x - 5y + 2z\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&2z\equiv -4x+5y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&7(2z)\equiv 7(-4x+5y)\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&14z\equiv -28x+35y)\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&z\equiv\;11x+9y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, to satisfy the hypothesis, we can let $x,y$ be arbitrary integers, and then let $z$ be any integer such that
$$z\equiv\;11x+9y\;(\text{mod}\;13)$$

Analyzing the choices one at a time, we get
\begin{align*}
a&=x + 13y - z\\[4pt]
&\equiv x+13y -(11x+9y)\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv -10x+4y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv 3x+4y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[12pt]
b&=6x - 10y - z\\[4pt]
&\equiv 6x-10y -(11x+9y)\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv -5x-19y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv 8x+7y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[12pt]
c&=x - y - 2z\\[4pt]
&\equiv x-y -2(11x+9y)\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv -21x-19y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv 5x+7y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[12pt] 
d&=-7x +12 y +3z\\[4pt]
&\equiv -7x+12y+3(11x+9y)\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv 26x+39y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[12pt] 
e&=-5x +3y - 4z\\[4pt]
&\equiv-5x+3y -4(11x+9y)\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv -49x-33y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv 3x+6y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[12pt] 
\end{align*}
Thus, since the integers $x,y$ can be chosen arbitrarily, choice $(\text{D})$ is the only one which *must* be a multiple of $13$.

More generally, assume the hypothesis 
$$13{\,\mid\,}(4x - 5y + 2z)\qquad (*)$$
where $x,y,z$ are unknown integers, and let $p$ be given by
$$p=Rx+Sy+Tz$$
where $R,S,T$ are given integers.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
p&=Rx+Sy+Tz\\[4pt]
&\equiv Rx+Sy+T(11x+9y)\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv (R+11T)x+(S+9T)y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
&\equiv (R-2T)x+(S-4T)y\;(\text{mod}\;13)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, assuming $(*)$, we get that $p$ is necessarily a multiple of $13$ if and only if the conditions
$$
\begin{cases}
13{\,\mid\,}(R-2T)\\[6pt]
13{\,\mid\,}(S-4T)\\
\end{cases}
$$
are satisfied, or equivalently, $R,S,T$ are given by
$$
\begin{cases}
R=2t+13u\\[4pt]
S=4t+13v\\[4pt]
T=t\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $t,u,v$ are arbitrary integers.

Comment: +1. Thank you for answer. I learned new ideas in congruent.

Comment: @AvinashN  It can actually be done much more quickly - see my answer

Answer (score 3):

> If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers satisfying $13 \mid  4x - 5y + 2z$, which one of the following sums must also be divisible by $13$?
>
> $(A)\ x\! +\! 13y\! -\! z,\ (B)\ 6x\! -\! 10y\! -\! z,\ (C)\ x\! -\! y\! -\! 2z,\ (D)\ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid green]{{\color{#c00}{-7}}x\! +\! 12y\! +\! \color{#c00}3z},\ (E)\ {-}5x\! +\! 3y\!-\! 4z$

Easy way: Let $f = 4x-5y+2z.\,$ If $13\nmid n$ then $13\mid nf\iff 13\mid f,\,$ so it suffices to see if one has the form $nf$. If so the $x$ coef will remain twice the $z$ coef $\!\bmod 13.\,$ Checking only $(D)$ works

$(A)\ \ 1\not\equiv 2(-1),\ \ (B)\ \  6\not\equiv 2(-1),\ \ (C)\ \  1\not\equiv 2(-2),\ \ (D)\ \  \bbox[5px,border:1px solid green]{\color{#c00}{{-}7}\equiv 2(\color{#c00}3)}, \ \ (E)\  {-5}\not\equiv 2(-4)$

$(D)$ is $\,g\equiv 6x\!-\!y\!+\!3z.\,$ $f\,$ has $-5y\,$ vs $-y$ in $g\,$  so $\,5g \equiv 30x -5y +15z\equiv f\pmod{\!13}$

Comment: +1.Thank you sir.. fully different ideas... I am wondering... Anyhow I am going to read again for better understanding...